# Endless Running Goroutine Terminates Without Panic

Tags: go, parallel-processing, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, goroutine

I need to monitor the status of the N sensors and log it. I am creating a separate goroutine for each sensor which fetches the state and logs it at regular intervals. For each goroutine, a channel is created to read the termination signal. Each sensor's state is maintained in sync.Map. The map maintains a pointer to the state. Apart from monitoring goroutines, there are processing goroutines that update the sensor's state.

In my current implementation, the goroutines are able to log the status at regular intervals. But after a few days, some goroutines stop logging the status. But the processing goroutines are able to update the status.

As a goroutine may terminate if panic occurs, I used recover() to log the error and the monitoring thread is re-created. But this doesn't help either. I noticed that the goroutine has been terminated but error hasn't been logged.

I suspect that because of memory leak, the goroutine might be terminated.

Sample Code:

```
// sensor state struct
type sensorState struct {
    a float64
    b int
    lock sync.Mutex
    ch   chan int
}

type curStatus struct {
    a float64
    b int
    ...
}

// log struct
type stateLog struct {
    state curStatus
    timestamp int64
    method string
}

// stateMap maintains state of different sensors 
var stateMap sync.Map
stateMap.Store("Sensor-A", &sensorState{
                      a : 0,
                      b : 0,
                      lock : sync.Mutex{},
                      ch : make(chan int)
               })


func ChargerMonitoringThreadV2(sensorId string) {

    isStateLocked := false
    sensorStatus := curStatus{}

    sessionState, _ := stateMap.Load(sensorId)
    state, _ := sessionState.(*sensorState)

    defer func() {
        if er := recover(); er != nil {
            fmt.Printf("ERROR: [sensorId:%s][ChargerMonitoringThreadV2] Recovered from - %v", sensorId, er)
            fmt.Printf("ERROR: [sensorId:%s][ChargerMonitoringThreadV2] stacktrace from panic:\n%s", sensorId, string(debug.Stack()))

            if isStateLocked {
                fmt.Printf("INFO: [sensorId:%s][ChargerMonitoringThreadV2] Released  lock\n", sensorId)
                state.lock.Unlock()
                isStateLocked = false
            }

            go ChargerMonitoringThreadV2(sensorId)
            logging.ReportException(fmt.Errorf("%v\n%s", er, string(debug.Stack()))) // log error
            return
        }
    }()

    for {
        select {
        
        case <-state.ch:
            fmt.Printf("INFO: [sensorId:%s][monitoringThread] Terminating monitoring thread...\n", sensorId)
            return
            
        default:

            curTS := time.Now().UnixMilli()

            state.lock.Lock()
            isSessionStateLocked = true

            sensorStatus.a = state.a

            state.lock.Unlock()
            isSessionStateLocked = false

            insertLog(&stateLog{
                state:     sensorStatus,
                timestamp: curTS,
                method:    "monitoringThread",
            })

            time.Sleep(60 * time.Second)
        }
    }
}
```

It will be helpful if someone explains this abnormal behavior and provides possible solutions.
Thanks

Comment: start by checking the program with the race detector. If you are running out of memory, the OS is going to terminate the program outside of your control. You should not need to try and recover like this, because there is no code to panic here outside of severe errors which should crash the entire program anyway. Let it panic and fix the programming errors. If you are unsure of the status of your program, get a stack trace and see what every goroutine is actually doing.

Comment: (in a polling loop like this, it would be better to wait in a case statement rather than `time.Sleep` so that you can actually receive from `<-state.ch` when a signal is sent)

Comment: can you share full code? like a playground link?